# Git GPG password in keyring

Tags: linux, git, gnupg

I'm using git with GnuPG signing. Each time I want to sign a commit I have to provide my GnuPG key password.

Is it possible to make git take advantage of some system-wide keyring, like `gnome-keyring`? I can't seem to find any documentation on that, or even any thread on this in the web. Perhaps there is some solution I'm not aware of, that is not popular enough to be easy to google.

There are probably some GUI tools that can do that for me, but I'm not interested in those, I mostly use git from console, sometimes from IntelliJ-based IDEs, which just invoke the system `git` binary. Having a system-side solution will allow me to use `git config --global commit.gpgsign true` with these IDEs (and cli).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/624343/keep-gnupg-credentials-cached-for-entire-user-session) can answer your question?

Comment: It kinda did. I had to write a small script to make the agent work on fedora, but now it remembers my password, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from https://superuser.com/questions/624343/keep-gnupg-credentials-cached-for-entire-user-session

> ### Up to GnuPG 2
>
> The user configuration (in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`) can only define
>   the default and maximum caching duration; it can't be disabled.
>
> The `default-cache-ttl` option sets the timeout (in seconds) after the
>   last GnuPG activity (so it resets if you use it), the
>   `maximum-cache-ttl` option set the timespan (in seconds) it caches
>   after entering your password. The default value is 7200 (2 hours) for
>   both.
>
> Set it to a year or so – say, 34560000 seconds (400 days) – and you
>   should be fine:
>
> ```
> default-cache-ttl 34560000
> maximum-cache-ttl 34560000
> ```
>
> But for this change to take effect, you need to end the session by
>   restarting gpg-agent.
>
> If you want to limit to your session length, you'd need to kill the
>   daemon at logout. This is very different between operating systems, so
>   I'm referring to another question/answer containing [hints for
>   different
>   systems](https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux).
>
> You could also restart the `gpg-agent` during login, but this does not
>   limit caching time to the session length, but logins of a user. Decide
>   yourself if this is a problem in your case.
>
> ### GnuPG 2.1 and above
>
> In GnuPG 2.1 and above, the `maximum-cache-ttl` option was renamed to
>   `max-cache-ttl` without further changes.

Comment: All that's also required is to have a correct value in `GPG_AGENT_INFO` environment variable - at least for fedora 23.

Answer (score 1):

I see you use Fedora, in version 29, all I had to do was:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg2
```

And it uses the Gnome Keychain (seahorse).